# Power sets of a null set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I came across this question. 
P (A)=?
P (P (A))=?
P (P (P (A)))=?
Where A is the null set
Solving the 1st one I got "1"
Then in the second I got "2" with the power sets phi and 1
Then in the 2nd one I got "2" with power sets a phi and 2
Are these answers correct.
Thanks in advance......
Note:P () means power sets.

Answer (score 1):

$P(\emptyset)=\{\emptyset\}$. A power set of a singleton has $2$ elements, here $\bigl\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\bigr\}.$ Next a power set of a $2$-element set contains $2^2=4$ elements. So, the consecutive power sets have cardinalities being the powers of $2$.